# Weak convergence of bounded nets

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ be a bounded net in $c_0$. For all $\alpha\in A$, let $x_\alpha = (x_\alpha^n)\in c_0$; if, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $(x_\alpha^n)_{\alpha\in A}$ is a net that converges to $x_{n}$ in $\mathbb{C}\text{ or in }\mathbb{R}$, how to prove that $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ converges to $(x_n)$ in the weak topology of $c_0$?

Comment: First step, take a convenient representation of the continuous linear functionals on $c_0$.

Comment: The $0^{\text{th}}$ step would be to show that the pointwise limit actually belongs to $c_0$. Unfortunately, we can't, the pointwise limit can be any element of $\ell^\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences
$$
(1,0,0,\ldots),
$$
$$
(1,0,1,0,0,\ldots),
$$
$$
(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,\ldots),
$$
etc.

The pointwise limit is
$$
(1,0,1,0,1,\ldots),
$$
which is not in $c_0$.